# jquery to php code then to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to pass information from jquery to a database.

I have the function in jquery already submitting etc but unsure where to go now.

The php I want to get to will be requesting the data but the bit im unsure with is passing my data to this page? PLease not the //NEED TO ADD SOMETHING HERE? bit.

I know I Need to add something like a post but unsure how to do this using jquery.

Below is the jquery code:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 600,
  width: 1000,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Create Property": function() {
      var bValid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "name", 3, 16 );
      bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "address1", 6, 80 );
      bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "address2", 5, 16 );

      if ( bValid ) {

        ***//NEED TO ADD SOMETHING HERE?*** 

        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
 });
```

Below is the php page I want to pass the data to:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit-property']))
{  
  //Create a new object
  $property = new Property(""); 

//Collect the variables passed from REQUEST
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$address1 = $_REQUEST['address1'];   
$address2 = $_REQUEST['address2'];
$address3 = $_REQUEST['address3'];
$address4 = $_REQUEST['address4'];
$postCode = $_REQUEST['postCode'];

etc etc etc
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks alot.

Comment: AH sorry. I should of said. It's just checking to see if the fields are valid. The names of the fields that I need to post to the php page are name, address1 and address2. Everything works apart from I don't know what the code would be to pass (post) this information to another page.

Comment: You need first read up on how to post to a php page. You can find simple example at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ should be fairly simple to figure out.

Comment: You might want to use an ajax request... though, you might also decide to instead use a postback. There's plenty of existing examples and tutorials to help you send your first ajax request. Try it yourself, then, when you have problems, ask here. At this point you don't have a problem for us to help you solve.

Comment: $('#yourform').serialize() will help you on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's ajax function for example:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/